# Exporting multiple glm plots as PNGs?

Tags: r, png, plot, glm

SO,

I'm trying to export plots of my linear model.  When I do it as a PDF, the PDF has four pages and four different charts.  When I export as a PNG, I only get the first chart.  How do I export so that I get all four graphs as separate PNG files?

What worked with the PDF:

```
lrfitX11SUMS <- glm(X11SUMS ~ POLITA + CIRCULATION + COMPAPER + TrafficRankUS, data=NewspTest)

    summary(lrfitOTONE)
    pdf("/Users/william/Desktop/output/lmfitOTONE1.pdf")
    plot(lrfitOTONE)
    dev.off()
```

What DIDN'T WORK with PNG (and spent two hours digging around on the internet and in the plot documentation to no avail):

```
lrfitX11SUMS <- glm(X11SUMS ~ POLITA + CIRCULATION + COMPAPER + TrafficRankUS, data=NewspTest)

summary(lrfitOTONE)
png("/Users/william/Desktop/output/lmfitOTONE1.png", width=720, height=720, pointsize=16)
png("/Users/william/Desktop/output/lmfitOTONE2.png", width=720, height=720, pointsize=16)
png("/Users/william/Desktop/output/lmfitOTONE3.png", width=720, height=720, pointsize=16)
png("/Users/william/Desktop/output/lmfitOTONE4.png", width=720, height=720, pointsize=16)
plot(lrfitOTONE)
dev.off()
```

How do I get my images?

Thanks,

-Wm

Answer (score 8):

A PDF allows multipage documents. A PNG image is fundamentally incompatible with this idea. Reading `?png` and appreciating the need to look at the `filename` argument would have directed you to `?postscript` for the details.

You want something like:

```
png("/Users/william/Desktop/output/lmfitOTONE%1d.png", width=720, 
    height=720, pointsize=16)
plot(lrfitOTONE)
dev.off()
```

where the `%1d` in the filename is a wildcard that expands to a 1 digit numeric value such that you get four figures with the names you wanted. Your 4 calls to `png()` set up four separate devices, only the latter of which was used and subsequently closed, the other three remained open.

Comment: Do note Ben's comments in his Answer regarding getting the plot method to draw individual plots. My Answer assumes the display isn't split into multiple panels - which it isn't unless you did anything to make it so.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
setwd("/Users/william/Desktop/output/")
tmpf <- function(i) {
   png(paste("lmfitOTONE",i,".png",sep=""), width=720, height=720, pointsize=16)
}
wplot <- c(1,2,3,5) ## see ?plot.lm for definition of 'which'
for (i in seq_along(wplot)) {
   tmpf(i); plot(lrfitOTONE, which=wplot[i]); dev.off()
}
```

The key is realizing that `plot.lm` (which is the method used by `plot` applied to a `glm` object, because `glm` is a subclass of `lm` and doesn't have its own particular plot method) displays diagnostic plots based on the `which` argument, and the default value of `which` is the same as `wplot` above.  So basically: figure out how to create the individual sub-plots.

Comment: +1 for the info about the `plot.lm` method and how to plot individual figures via `which`.

Comment: @user1017124 -- Unless I'm misinterpreting, you sound pleased ;) Another way to show that is to 'accept' one of these two excellent answers, by clicking the check-mark next to it. Thanks to you for your question and the answers it provoked.